# Need to update my regex pattern to match roman numerals

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this pattern: `[ ]\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b` to match all roman numerals in a string.
Here are some examples of what I needed:

`string1 VI
STRING4 I
STRING5 1340 I
2 STRING6 III
STRING7 V
STRING11 STRING12 VI
STRING13! IX
STRING14 VI
. STRING15 
- STRING16_ V
STRING17 1/2 VI
STRING18 VIII
XIII (2011)
V (2012)
String19 VP
XII`

will result in:

`string1 
STRING4 
STRING5 1340 
2 STRING6 
STRING7 
STRING11 STRING12 
STRING13! 
STRING14 
. STRING15 
- STRING16_ 
STRING17 1/2 
STRING18 
XIII (2011) 
V (2012) 
String19 VP 
XII`

Now the problem is that I have this string: `WORD1 DI WORD2` and the pattern above matches `DI`.
But I want it to remain: `WORD1 DI WORD2`, so I want to match roman numerals only when they are at the end of a string (except when there is only one word like `XII`).

So I still want to keep the results above, but I need to add a rule to obtain this:

`WORD1 DI WORD2` -> `WORD1 DI WORD2`

Any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use :

```
$result = preg_replace("/\s(I|V|X|L|M|D|C)+$/gm", "", $str);
```

This gives expected result for your examples.

Comment: It does for single lines just add global and multiline modifiers > check edit

Comment: Oh sorry thanks :), but it matches the single string `XII` too.
Edit: I solved it using: `[ ](I|V|X|L|M|D|C)+$`

Comment: The g modifier doesn't exist in PHP (`preg_replace` performs a global replacement by default). Replacing `M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})` with `(I|V|X|L|M|D|C)+` (that is better written: `[IVXLMDC]+`) is not a good idea since it may return more false positive: `"Magic Mike XXL"`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, ok thanks, so what do you think to solve my problem?